# ServiceStack return response syntax error

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am just quickly upgrading ServiceStack to version 4.5.4 and I am having a problem trying to convert my service. Basically I cannot longer return the sql response as a string. Does anyone know the correct syntax for this?

I have managed to change to the new syntax, however I am not able to find the correct way to change the following line:

> return new PostAccountResponse() { message = string.Format("{0}",
>   message.Value };

```
public object Post(Account.Model.Account request)
        {
            switch (request.Accounttype)
            {
                case "dview":
                    try
                    {
                        return dbFactory.Exec(dbCmd =>

                        {
                            dbCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            dbCmd.CommandText = "stored procedure...";
                            dbCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@mobile", request.mobile));
                            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter message = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@message", "");
                            message.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                            dbCmd.Parameters.Add(message);
                            gender.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                            r = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
                            return new PostAccountResponse() { message = string.Format("{0}", message.Value };
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                       //
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return new object();

        }
```

Does anyone know how to correctly return the response for my service? Thank you so much. I experimented with the following but also didn't work:

```
    var rdr = dbCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                            var results = new List<Account.Model.PostAccountResponse>();
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                results.Add(new Account.Model.PostAccountResponse { message = string.Format("{0}", message.Value) });
                            }
return new PostAccountResponse { message = results };
```

**UPDATED 1**

I mam trying to upgrade a service to the latest version and the code doesn't compile anymore with this new version. That's what I mean by doesn't work. The compiler throws these errors on the return new PostAccountResponse line:

1.- Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value.

2.- Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

3.- Cannot implicitly convert type 'Account.Model.PostAccountResponse' to 'System.Data.IDbCommand'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

4.- Cannot implicitly convert type 'Account.Model.PostAccountResponse' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Comment: You can return raw strings in a ServiceStack Service, but as a matter of good design your Services should return the same Response Type in all code paths. You also shouldn't return `object`, you can return `null` if you don't want a response. Please update your question to clarify exactly what you mean by "doesn't work" including any Exception Stack Traces, please also include the raw HTTP Request/Response Headers so we can see exactly what's being returned vs what you're expecting.

Comment: thanks @mythz for you reply. Please see the updated question. I wrote this service years ago and has been always working just fine until now. The problem is that I just upgraded servicestack and that's why the syntax now changed. I just want to learn how can I now return the response from MySQL on my service. If you have any idea on the above, I will be more than glad to hear it, thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `dbFactory.Exec()` you should use a DB connection in a using statement like:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
using (var dbCmd = db.CreateCommand())
{
    dbCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dbCmd.CommandText = "stored procedure...";
    dbCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@mobile", request.mobile));
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter message = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@message", "");
    message.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    dbCmd.Parameters.Add(message);
    gender.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    r = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
    return new PostAccountResponse() { message = string.Format("{0}", message.Value };
}
```

You're trying to use a raw ADO.NET connection here to call a MySql Stored procedure, but normally when you're accessing your database using [OrmLite APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) you can just use `base.Db` ADO.NET Connection directly, e.g:

```
return Db.Select<Table>();
```

Comment: thanks again @mythz, a very stupid question sorry, I am replace the return dbFactory.Exec(dbCmd => { ... } with using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection()) { ... } , however I ran into an error IDbConnection does not contain a definition for 'CommandType', 'CommandText' and 'Parameters'. Any idea on what I am doing wrong? :(

Comment: @carol1287 Sorry flying blind, you need to create the `IDbCommand` see the updated answer.